# Get android context inside Acra reportSender implementation

Tags: android, android-context, acra

Is there a way to get android context inside custom ACRA ReportSender implementation class?

```
public class MyReportSender implements ReportSender {
    public ErrorReportSender(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save reference to object of your `Application` implementation into the static variable and get it using static method:

```
    private static Application sInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate ()
{
    sInstance = this;
    ACRA.init( this );
    super.onCreate();
}
public static Application getInstance()
{
  return sInstance;
}
```

Comment: Thx, didn't remember the static option!